# jquery - cant send "@" in a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

im a noob at jquery, but learning fast.

ive been using $.post to send values from a html form to a php file. And everyone works until an email address is entered contain the "@" symbol (which they all do of course) then it breaks!

im being experimental with my jquery a lot. and what im trying to do is not use the form tags in the html.

Meh, read the code. You'll see what I mean. I'm taking out all the validating and error reporting so it's not a epic tl:dr read...

```
<table id='contactform'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for='name'>Name</label>
            <input id='name' type='text'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for='phone'>Phone</label>
            <input id='phone' type='tel'>
        </td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <label for='email'>Email</label>
            <input id='email' type='email'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <label for='message'>Message</label>
            <textarea id='message'></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>
            <button id='sendmessage'>SEND MESSAGE</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The js, minus validation checks...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input#name").focus();
$("button#sendmessage").click(function() {
    $("table#contactform").hide();
    $("div#popin").show();
    $("div#popin").html("<img src='images/loader.gif'>");
    sendmessage();
});
});

function sendmessage() {
$.post(
    "sendmessage.php",
    {nameval:$("input#name").val(), phoneval:$("input#phone").val(),  emailval:$("input#email").val(), messageval:$("textarea#message").val()},
    function(data) {
        if (data == true) {
            $("div#popin").html("<p>We have received your message and will reply asap</p>");
        }
        else {
            $("div#popin").html("<p>Something went wrong! Please contact webmaster@******</p>");
        }
    }
);
}
```

So, everything gets sent to the php file fine. It reads the post values, emails them to me fine, returns the data 'true' to the js... until there's a "@" in the email!!!

I know I could use serialize_data() or whatever it is, but I'm hoping to not to have use forms. Oh yea, and this worked...

```
var emailval = $("input#email").val().replace("@", "(at)");
$.post(
    "funcs/contact.php",
    {nameval:$("input#name").val(), phoneval:$("input#phone").val(), emailval:emailval, messageval:$("textarea#message").val()},
```

But no matter what I replace the "@" with, when I use str_replace in the php file, it just breaks again.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Here's the php...

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["nameval"];
$phone = $_POST["phoneval"];
$email = $_POST["emailval"];
$message = $_POST["messageval"];
$emailbody = "Name - $name\nPhone - $phone\nEmail - $email\n\n$message";
$recipient = "webmaster@*****";
$subject = "contact form";
$result = mail($recipient, $subject, $emailbody, "From:$email");
if ($result) {
    echo true;
}
else {
    echo false;
}
?>
```

Comment: Try escaping the email before posting it. `escape(emailval)`

Comment: Your last few lines confuse me. What do you mean with 'Break again when i use str_replace in php'? In php str_replace just returns a string. Nothing to break there. What isn't working when the @ is the string? My guess is the problem is with your PHP code. What is the output if contact.php just contains print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: I mean, I use replace() in the js, then use str_replace in the php to swap it back, and the php files doesn't return 'true'...

Comment: ill add the php to the main post
thanka very much for the quick reply, but escape() doesn't fix it

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the PHP code, not JS. Can you show us what is going on in PHP? Then we can help you

Comment: php added
i just dont see what can be wrong. it's so simple.
i can use replace() in the js to send "testmctest(at)test.test" to the php file, but if i use str_replace to turn the string back to an email address... breakage!
slashes work! but again, when i strip the slash in the php file... breakage :(

Comment: fixed!!!
it was the php. "From:$email"; was breaking it, but "Reply-To:$email"; is ok. combining that with escape() in the js, makes it work great.
thank you ppl :D

Answer (score 0):

You can look at encodeURIComponent() javascript method, no need to decode it at server side:

```
emailval:encodeURIComponent($("input#email").val())
```